# Gesture Priority SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I am trying to make a horizontal list view which is in a scrollview and lets me LongPress an element pick pick it up and rearrange the order.  I cannot seem to have have the dragGesture in the parent view and the LongPress gesture in the childView work simultaneously.  I have tried highPriorityGesture which overrides the childView's gesture, and without it, the scroll view's drag gesture is overridden.  Would appreciate some help.

```
struct CustomHList<T:View>: View {
    
    @Binding var items:[T]
    @Binding var activeItem:Int
    @Binding var editing:Bool
    
    @State private var editingInd:Int? = nil
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @GestureState private var isHolding = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        return VStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack{
                
                ForEach(0..<items.count){ind in
                    
                        items[ind]
                            .offset(editingInd != nil && editingInd == ind ? offset:CGSize.zero)
                            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.5)
                                        .updating($isHolding) {currentstate, gestureState, transaction in
                                            gestureState = currentstate

                                        }
                                        .onEnded { value in
                                            withAnimation {
                                                isDragging = true
                                                
                                            }
                                            

                                            
                                        }
                            .sequenced(before: DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged{value in self.offset = value.translation}
                                        .onEnded { _ in
                                            withAnimation {
                                                offset = .zero
                                                isDragging = false
                                            }
                                            editingInd = 100
                                        }))
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }
               
            }
        }.highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())
            Text("\(editingInd ?? 100)")
            Text(isHolding ? "Yes":"No")
        }
    }
}
```